# What's the meaning of "religious belief" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

My **religious beliefs** forbid the drinking of alcohol.

I think it implies—My certainty about my religion...

Comment: It means 'the particular beliefs/teachings of the religion I belong to'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means your personally-held beliefs due to your membership of, or alignment with, a particular religion.

One possible reason for saying "*my religious beliefs forbid...*" rather than simply "*my religion forbids...*" is that it sounds more like you are making the decision based on what you believe, rather than an organised religion making the decision for you. So, yes - it does *imply* some certainty, but it doesn't explicitly mean that.

Answer (score 1):

The word **beliefs** is also used by people to refer to the strictures of their religion, restrictions upon behavior, or to behaviors demanded of its adherents, rules relating to food, say, or the time and manner of prayer, or about clothing, and so forth. Such behaviors are considered "expressions" of their faith and there is a supposed metaphysical aspect to these customs.